# How to shorten python plot time when there are many data points?

Tags: python, performance, plot

I'm drawing a plot with python. Code is below. When there are only a few hundreds of data points, the code executes well and returns fairly quick; but when there are 200k data points, it need a few hours. I need shorten the time. But how? Thanks.

```
import numpy as np;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;

oneD = [];
#read in lines and append to oneD
oneD.append(float(aVariable));
oneD = (np.array(oneD));
oneD = oneD[ind];
x = np.arange(len(oneD));
#following line takes long time to execute
#print timestamp
plt.bar(x, oneD, width, edgecolor='orange', color='orange', alpha=0.7); 
#print timestamp
```

Comment: Don't put semicolons at the end of each line. Python doesn't need them.

Comment: i knew that. kind of habit from perl programming. it won't hurt, right. thanks.

Comment: @TonyXu can you bin your data?